# Cannot uncheck UITableViewCell in segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have such code in my segue from a button in navigation bar of `UITableViewController`:

```
if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"groupInitialSelect"]) {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.lastIndexPath];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    [self.tableView scrollRectToVisible:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1) animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
    TTPDepartment *dep = [self.departmentList objectAtIndexedSubscript:self.lastIndexPath.row];
    TTPGroupViewController *controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    controller.selectedDepartment = dep;
}
```

When I perform a segue and come back I see that the cell is still checked. Strangely, `scrollRectToVisible` is scrolling back to the top on the same time.

`self.lastIndexPath` is updated on each selection:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath;
{
self.lastIndexPath = indexPath;
self.nextButton.enabled = YES;
[tableView reloadData];
}
```

I check the list element in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
if ([indexPath compare:self.lastIndexPath] == NSOrderedSame)
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
}
else
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you're setting the `accessoryType` to none for the last selected cell and then You call `reloadData`, but in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath`: the `lastIndexPath` is still the same and you're setting the checkmark. 
Try to set to nil `lastIndexPath` before the call to `reloadData`.